# After refreshing page not all images are loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im doing fullstack project with Java Spring REST and Angular/JS is giving me some serious problems. I have main page where I display 9 random products (games). I make http call to get product info and path to the image (which is saved on the server). After getting imagepath I make http call to get image. On the backend everything works fine - both getting game info and getting image.

However after refreshing page not all images are shown - sometimes it shows 1 out of 9, sometimes 5 and sometimes none. If I dont refresh the page and make same call again (by pressing a button), all images are properly displayed. Im pretty sure I dont understand something about asynchronous calls. I'm trying to figure it out for several days but with no success...

Page:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in games track by $index">
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4" style="padding-bottom: 15px">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>{{ x.gameName }}</h3>
                                <img height="200" width="330" data-ng-src="{{ x.gameImage }}">
                                <p>Genre: {{ x.genre }}</p>
                                <p>Price: {{ x.price }}$</p>
                                <p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="details" href="gameDetails.html" ng-click="goToTheGameDetails()">
                                        <span class="glyphicon-info-sign glyphicon" /></span> Details
                                    </a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Controller:

```
GetRandomGames.getRandomGames($http).then( function(randomGames) { 
    angular.forEach( randomGames, function(game) {
        var promise =  GetImageForGame.getImageForGame(game.imagePath, $http, $location );
        promise.then(
            function(image){
                var fileReader  = new FileReader();
                fileReader.addEventListener("load", function () {
                    game.gameImage = fileReader.result;
                }, false);
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(image.data);          
            },
            function(){
                console.log("Error");
            }
        );
    });
    $scope.games = randomGames;
});
```

Service:

```
this.getImageForGame = function( imagePath, $http, $location ){ 
    var absUrl = $location.absUrl().replace(/OnlineGameStore.*$/, '');
    var completeUrl = absUrl + "OnlineGameStore/getGamePhoto/" + imagePath;
    return $http( {
        method: 'GET',
        url: completeUrl,
        responseType: "blob"
    });
};
```

Edit: I've just noticed - after doing something on website (for example selecting option from select list) all the missing images are properly loaded.

Comment: Does the request return with an image file, or a url to an image file? If the request gives you an image file, you could use the url of the request directly in the `img` tag. You do not need to read the blob. Can you show us the response of that request?

Comment: There are 2 requests - one returns product info with image path (lets say its url). Based on the image path I make another request - it returns byte image which I later convert with "fileReader.readAsDataURL(); ". I have no idea if thats the correct way to do this but I wanted it to be entirely REST service.

Comment: You don't need the second request (not explicitly, at least). You can just set the image path as src to the image tag. The browser will fetch the image for you.

Comment: Oh, I didnt think about it... I will change it and see if the problem still occurs. However I think it only works around the problem, not solves it. What if some REST service would only return the blob and I *had* to convert it?

Comment: What you are doing is alright. You will have to write the blob to a variable in scope in the request's callback and use that in the `img`'s `data-ng-src`. Note that that has to be in the full Data URI scheme: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0...". I think this is what's missing in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your help - I still couldnt resolve my original problem but I've done it your (much easier) way. However I'm still curious what was the problem there, maybe someone will know...